# Why hasnt key= been documented?

Tags: python, python-3.x

im a begginer so i might be straight up wrong in asking this but i was following a course and i was confused on how to sort a dictionary using a function, with the function returning the key inside that dictionary. iv had to do some testing to see what conditions i can use the key= for, i realised i could use it on max, but when trying to use it with sort i was stumped, i looked online for how to use key= and all i got was keys(), am i missing some understanding or has this been something not well doccumented?

what i tried:

```
def name_alphabetical(student):
    return student["name"]
students = [
    {"name": "Hannah", "grade_average": 83},
    {"name": "Charlie", "grade_average": 91},
    {"name": "Peter", "grade_average": 85},
    {"name": "Rachel", "grade_average": 79},
    {"name": "Lauren", "grade_average": 92}
]

print(students.sort(key(name_alphabetical))
```

what worked:

```
def n(student):
    return student["name"]


students = [
    {"name": "Hannah", "grade_average": 83},
    {"name": "Charlie", "grade_average": 91},
    {"name": "Peter", "grade_average": 85},
    {"name": "Rachel", "grade_average": 79},
    {"name": "Lauren", "grade_average": 92}
]

students.sort(key=n)
print(students)
```

resault seeked:

```
[{'name': 'Charlie', 'grade_average': 91}, {'name': 'Hannah', 'grade_average': 83}, {'name': 'Lauren', 'grade_average': 92}, {'name': 'Peter', 'grade_average': 85}, {'name': 'Rachel', 'grade_average': 79}]
```

Comment: [Doc on the key parameter for sorting methods](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#key-functions). `key=` is a keyword argument for `sort()`.

Comment: Where did you look? `keys()` is a method of dictionaries, it has nothing to do with sorting lists.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for narrow, specific practical problems you actually face. If you know the behavior and how to use it, you don't have a practical problem. Requests for off-site resources (like external documentation links) are explicitly off-topic, as are "rants in disguise" ("questions" that are actually complaints).

Comment: Sort key is literally the first thing that shows up in pylance when you view function details in vscode.

Comment: `key` is a parameter of the function `sort`. It should be documented within [`sort`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort)'s documentation. Other functions may have a keyword parameter `key` that may do something completely unrelated.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Asking why an attempted solution doesn't work is a valid question.

Comment: The first google result after searching sort list by key gives you an example with `key=`. It was in lambda format but still.

Comment: @Squarish He knows how to use `key=`, it's in the second code snippet.

Comment: @Barmar I know he knows it works. But he's saying it's not documented which is completely incorrect.

Comment: @Squarish Yes, I know. But an example of using it is not documentation (unless it happens to be in the python doc page).

Comment: @Barmar, is that what the OP is asking? The title is a question about off-site documentation, and the OP clearly knows how to write correct code, even if they tried something that they know to be incorrect first.

Comment: @Barmar It is the python doc website. [This page](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) specifically

Comment: @CharlesDuffy you could have bothered to point me in the right direction instead of repeating rules and regulations shpeel

Comment: @smellyalligator Someone else had already done that in the first comment.

Comment: `list.sort` is documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort). It includes a paragraph on `key`. Its used the same as in the `sort` function.

Comment: @barmar your right my bad, read his first as it was the beefier comment. my apologies!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It **is** documented for [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted):

> `sorted(iterable, /, *, key=None, reverse=False)`
>
> *key* specifies a function of one argument that is used to extract a comparison key from each element in *iterable* (for example, `key=str.lower`). The default value is `None` (compare the elements directly).

and [`list.sort()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort):

> `sort(*, key=None, reverse=False)`
>
> *key* specifies a function of one argument that is used to extract a comparison key from each list element (for example, `key=str.lower`). The key corresponding to each item in the list is calculated once and then used for the entire sorting process. The default value of `None` means that list items are sorted directly without calculating a separate key value.

You can also use the REPL for a more compact version of the docs:

> ```
> >>> help(list.sort)
>
> Help on method_descriptor:
>
> sort(self, /, *, key=None, reverse=False)
>
>     Sort the list in ascending order and return None.
>
>     The sort is in-place (i.e. the list itself is modified) and stable (i.e. the
>     order of two equal elements is maintained).
>
>     If a key function is given, apply it once to each list item and sort them,
>     ascending or descending, according to their function values.
>
>     The reverse flag can be set to sort in descending order.
> ```

Comment: thank you, honestly i tried a mix of approaches in looking it up, using quotes and still nothing

Comment: @smellyalligator: Look for the *function's* (or method's, or class's, as appropriate) documentation, not the specific argument names. Argument names are repeated a *lot*, especially generic ones like `key=`, and they won't mean the same thing; the function is what defines those names and what they mean. You should have been looking for `list.sort`, not `key=`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger you see iv followed a course and the demonstration was how functions can be passed as arguments, the guide didnt explain how sort worked with key= or the correct order for it to be written in, i tried a similar approach to how the author used it to get max, obviously applying the same formatting to sort() didnt work out.

Comment: @smellyalligator: Uh, `max`'s `key` argument is passed the exact same way, and has the exact same meaning, so I have no idea what you mean by "applying the same formatting to `sort` didn't work out". Regardless, if the guide doesn't explain things, go to the actual documentation for the function, don't just blindly guess at what to do and hope cargo cult programming saves the day.